# best opensource graph API to integrate with java

Tags: java

Suggest me a best opensource graph API to integrate with java application.
Basically it collects and stores some data.This collected data should be drawn in a graph like mothly average of data flow , weekly average ...The API should support extensive graph types like bar chart,pie chart , custom chart etc.,

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527640/java-graph-or-chart-library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JFreeChart is definitely a good one. You might find the following resources useful on understanding how to get started.

Gantt Chart
http://sanjaal.com/java/?p=343

3D Category Bar Chart
http://sanjaal.com/java/?p=321

3D Pie Chart
http://sanjaal.com/java/?p=318

Go through the API documentations. You will definitely find it worth using.

Answer (score 12):

I have used the [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) library for my charting needs. You still need to take care of storing the data yourself, though.